# Implementing Single Logout (SLO) with Sustainsys.Saml2 in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application that uses the **Sustainsys.Saml2.Owin** library for SAML 2.0 Single Sign-On (SSO) with Salesforce as the Identity Provider (IdP). SSO is working fine, but now I want to implement Single Logout (SLO) to ensure that when a user logs out of my application, they are also logged out of Salesforce. **How do I implement SLO in ASP.NET MVC?**
Following is how I implemented Saml2 based SSO.

```
public class Startup
{

public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{      

    
      app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Saml2",
            CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager(),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sessionTime"].ToString()))
        });

        app.UseSaml2Authentication(CreateSaml2Options());
}
private Saml2AuthenticationOptions CreateSaml2Options( )
{
    var saml2Options = new Saml2AuthenticationOptions(false)
    {
        SPOptions = new SPOptions
        {
            EntityId = new EntityId(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EntityId"].ToString()),
            ReturnUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReturnUrl"].ToString()),
        },
    };

    saml2Options.IdentityProviders.Add(
        new IdentityProvider(
            new EntityId(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IssuerUrl"].ToString()),
            saml2Options.SPOptions)
        {
            LoadMetadata = true,
            SingleSignOnServiceUrl= new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SingleSignOnServiceUrl"].ToString()),
            MetadataLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MetadataLocation"].ToString(),
            AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true,    
        });
    
    saml2Options.AuthenticationType = "Saml2";
    return saml2Options;
}
}
```